# script to generate commands to, move workstation from one zman-folder to another

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I run a command on the server which lists workstations in a folder.

based on the 1st 3 characters of the workstation name I want to move the workstation from the current folder to a new folder.

so the command: `zman wl /Workstation/Build` would list workstations in the Build folder as follows.

```
/Workstation/Build/red-001
/Workstation/Build/sci-001
/Workstation/Build/shs-001
```

Now I have a definitions file which tells me where to move the workstation to based on the 1st 3 characters of the workstation name.

```
red /Workstation/Staff/Red
sci /Workstation/Staff/Sci
shs /Workstation/Staff/Shs
```

So I am looking for a script or command which would list workstation in the "from" folder and then look up the 1st 3 characters of workstation name in definitions file to get the "to" folder and move the workstation there.

The move command would be.

```
zman wmv /Workstation/Build/Red-001 /Workstation/Staff/Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, for example, with a oneliner, like this one:

```
while read -r WORKSTATION; do echo "$WORKSTATION" "$(grep "$(basename "$WORKSTATION" | head -c 3)" "$TO_FILE_PATH" | cut -d' ' -f2)"; done < from_file
```

Its output would be:

```
/Workstation/Build/red-001 /Workstation/Staff/Red
/Workstation/Build/sci-001 /Workstation/Staff/Sci
/Workstation/Build/shs-001 /Workstation/Staff/Shs
```

---

`WORKSTATION` is just a name for the variable that will hold each *workstation path* for each iteration of the while loop.`TO_FILE_PATH` is the path of this file:

```
red /Workstation/Staff/Red
sci /Workstation/Staff/Sci
shs /Workstation/Staff/Shs
```

and `from_file`, is a file that contains this:

```
/Workstation/Build/red-001
/Workstation/Build/sci-001
/Workstation/Build/shs-001
```

---

Or, you can use a bash script, `move_worksations.sh`, like this one:

```
FROM_FILE_PATH="$1"
TO_FILE_PATH="$2"
WORKSTATION_NUMBER=0

while read -r WORKSTATION 
do
    WORKSTATIONS["$WORKSTATION_NUMBER"]=""$WORKSTATION" "$(grep "$(basename "$WORKSTATION" | head -c 3)" "$TO_FILE_PATH" | cut -d' ' -f2)""
    ((WORKSTATION_NUMBER++))
done < "$FROM_FILE_PATH"

for WS_SOURCE_TARGET in "${WORKSTATIONS[@]}"
    do zman wmv "$WS_SOURCE_TARGET"
done
```

And then, you use `move_worksations.sh`, this way:

```
./move_worksations.sh from_file to_file
```

Note: remember to give `move_worksations.sh` execution permission: `chmod u+x move_worksations.sh`